# Why do these characters appear when JavaScript is Disabled?

Tags: firefox, javascript

Anyone know why when JavaScript is disabled in firefox these characters show up? They replace images on the page. It isn't just a WordPress thing and they turn back into buttons when JavaScript is Enabled.

I'm curious why specifically these characters that differ for each image. I realize that JavaScript is used to put in the images.

The screen shot was taken inside a WordPress dashboard with ABP and NoScript enabled. Here is another example with the character near products and solutions: http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/

You will likely only see the error if you have the same configuration as I do. Firefox, Ubuntu, ABP, NoScript.

[image]

Comment: Because JavaScript is used to load images for the buttons?

Comment: Edited. I wanted to know why those particular characters. Is it a language? Why are the different for each?

Comment: What is the address of the website?

Comment: Please provide an easy-to-find example with an image of how it looks for you. I didn’t find anything on the Bloomberg page.

Comment: The only 'easy to find' example would be if you installed ABP/NoScript on Firefox on Ubuntu. Then visited that page. I can't find one for you because I think it requires one or the other or both to get this error.

Answer (score 2):

The icons come from an icon font, which is a special font where all the characters are icons.  That's why each character is different - different characters correspond to different icons in the font.

Since most people don't have such fonts installed on their computers, most websites that use them load them from either their own server or a 3rd-party CDN.  This is also commonly used to load other obscure fonts besides icon fonts.  Fonts loaded from a server rather than from your computer are sometimes called "webfonts."

WordPress's dashboard, for example, uses Open Sans for text.  However, the text in your screenshot is not in Open Sans.  That indicates that not only is the icon font not loading, neither is Open Sans.

Why aren't they loading?  I don't know.  Webfonts are sometimes loaded using JavaScript, but even disabling JavaScript I can't reproduce this on either a WordPress dashboard or on the Bloomberg site you linked to.  There's probably something else going on.  Maybe ABP is blocking the fonts for some reason.

**Edit:** Since your edit, I went and installed NoScript on my Firefox and tried again.  Before, I was disabling *just* JavaScript through the developer  console.  Now I can see what you're talking about.  NoScript is what's causing this.  It's not that it's blocking JavaScript, it's that it's blocking the fonts themselves.  The only difference for me is that I'm not seeing those characters, I'm seeing boxes with numbers in them.  But that's just because I'm on Windows, so it's falling back to Times New Roman, which doesn't contain any of those characters.  On your Ubuntu machine, whatever font it's falling back to actually contains those obscure characters WordPress is using.

Comment: Firefox has a preference "gfx.downloadable_fonts.enabled" which will preclude the use of webfonts if set to False. I believe NoScript has an option to toggle that pref, and of course any user can do likewise.

Comment: @kreemoweet When I installed NoScript, I didn't change any settings.  I just went with the defaults, and it was claiming responsibility for having blocked the fonts.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML renderer is interpreting the disabled script as double-byte characters from a font which you have installed.  If you did not have the font installed, you would instead get an image of two boxes with numbers in them stacked on top of each other which tells the user that there is supposed to be a double byte character there.  There's no special significance to the actual characters you see.

Comment: That sounds so far-fetched, it might as well be from outer space. No HTML renderer would ever randomly interpret anything, let alone a disabled script, as a multibyte character or whatever.

Comment: I should have been more careful with the semantics of my answer.  Indeed there is nothing to interpret, because the character value is always there.  It's just the rest of the instruction that's missing (javascript) so the character value comes through using defaults instead.